# What hour repeats in Daylight standard time

Tags: timezone, dst

I currently have a list of DateTimes stored as the timezone's UTC datetime. When I go to convert from UTC to local datetime and when the date falls on the start of Daylight Standard time, the hour that repeats is 1am and not 2am.

I use the following to convert from UTC to local time. Notice that 1am repeats in local1 and local2. I expected 2am to repeat.

Which is correct?

```
        TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
        //UTC time
        var utc1 = new DateTime(1990, 10, 28, 7, 0, 0);     //This is start of daylight standard time.
        var utc2 = new DateTime(1990, 10, 28, 8, 0, 0);
        var utc3 = new DateTime(1990, 10, 28, 9, 0, 0);
        utc1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utc1, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        utc2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utc2, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        utc3 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utc3, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        //Get the local time with adjustment for Daylight standard time, "fall back"
        var local1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc1, tz); //Returns 1am
        var local2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc2, tz); //Returns 1am. Should this be 2am?
        var local3 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc3, tz); //Returns 2am
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 2am you "fall back" to 1am (1:59 -> 1), hence 1am is repeated and 2am only occurs one hour later. similarly when you "spring forward" there would be NO 2 AM (1:59 -> 3)

source: http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/daylight_time.php  (US Naval Observatory keeps the US DoD official time (source for that: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/time))